# git cherry-pick succeeds but shows worktree as dirty due to eol mismatch

Tags: git, msysgit

I am trying to cherry-pick a change from another branch under Windows. The change creates a subdirectory and some files. While the command itself completes successfully, `git status` reports all new files as changed. `git diff` indicates a change in every line, but `git diff -w` comes out empty, indicating an EOL issue. Here are more details:

```
$ git reset --hard 6e9f9af
HEAD is now at 6e9f9af Hashing helper
$ git status
On branch newmaster
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git cherry-pick -m 1 5bd71b0
[newmaster d36aba2] <comment>
 Date: Sun Mar 27 19:21:35 2016 -0700
 37 files changed, 2552 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 src/phserver/winservice/Config.cpp
 . . . 
$ git status
On branch newmaster
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   winservice/Config.cpp
 . . .
```

What did not help:

- Setting repo's `core.autocrlf` to either `true`, `false` or `input` before the cherry-pick. This is interesting, as the files are new and not in the index before the command. Looks like I speak less Git than I thought...
- Attempting both Git for Windows 2.6.2 and Cygwin git 2.5.3.
- Using `git cherry-pick -Xignore-all-space`
- Modifying the cherry-pick commit. This worked *to a degree*:

  ```
  $ git cherry-pick -m 1 5bd71b0 -Xignore-all-space -n
  $ git add -u .
  $ git commit
  ```

  While that left the worktree clean, next cherry-picked patch failed horrifically due to eol mismatches--looks like this does not solve the issue in general, and only applicable when all files in the source commit are new.

I would appreciate suggestions, and, better yet, an explanation as to what is really going on.

Comment: Doing a `cherry-pick` is a bit like merging in a single commit.  I don't see anything in your setup whicb strikes me as either wrong or unexpected.  Line endings may be a problem but just treat it as you normally would.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Not sure I understand. "Normally" I would end up with a clean worktree after a cherry-pick, with `git status` showing nothing. In other words, normally I do not need to "treat" anything, but in my case I simply do not know what to do.

Comment: I don't believe this to be correct.  You can always get conflicts from a `cherry-pick` just as you can get conflicts from a `git merge`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Sure I can. Correction, then: normally, I end up with a clean worktree after cherry-pick succeeds without encountering a conflict. As is the case. Now I still do not see how this nitpicking helps me, sorry. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Try searching for how deal with line ending issues in general using Git.  Don't mention `cherry-pick`, because it is not the root cause of the problem.